# horizontal gradient on barchart [dc.js]

Tags: dc.js

Is there a dc.js solution to creating a horizontal gradient on individual bars?

So i'd like the gradients to be based on the filters selected

ie. there are 4 bars in total and i'd like it to go from yellow -> red

but when you select an individual bar, you will see yellow -> red on the same bar and if you select two bars, you'll see a gradient from the first bar to the second bar going from yellow -> red

Is there an easy to follow solution to this using dc.js?

[image]

I'd like to clarify that I need the gradients to span the individual bars as well

Here is an example below

https://gyazo.com/10cfd9bf29811e5a9f26163ec66c17e4

Comment: There's nothing built-in to do color gradients, so you'd have to do quite a bit of hacking to build [linearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients) objects in the `<defs>` section of the SVG, in response to the `pretransition` event, and then assign those gradients to the `rect`s by id. It's quite a bit of work, so I'm not going to write this for you today. Maybe someone else will be inspired.